# Is docker load balancing still working when Nginx and PHP-FPM communicate over the unix socket?

Tags: php, docker, sockets, unix, nginx

Let's say, we have two docker images in a docker-compose stack.
The first one is Nginx, the second one is PHP-FPM.

By default these images communicate over the TCP socket (*port 9000 usually*).
But the internet says, there is a more performant way to communicate - a unix socket.
As far as I know, **it's a pseudo-file**, like many others in Unix systems. So we'll have to mark the file as a volume.

Let's also say we have 3 replicas of PHP-FPM and 2 replicas of Nginx. So, when communicating over the TCP socket, the load balancing duty is up to internal Docker systems. But what about the Unix socket? Will Docker know which Unix socket should the call be redirected to?

Is it possible for docker-bases systems to balance **Unix socket** calls?

Comment: I don't think Docker on its own provides any automatic load balancing.  I also think you're not going to notice any difference in speed using a TCP vs. a Unix socket, especially given an interpreted backend language.  I'd stick with TCP sockets for simplicity and to support working in a multi-host environment.

Comment: @DavidMaze I guess you are right. Just was curious. Probably someone can give a piece of advice towards some simple and efficient ways to balance unix sockets?